# SparkContext Scala SourceCode : What is the functionality of "withScope " return type in textFile method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am currently learning Spark. While learning , I am simultaneously going through the sourcecode written in Scala (so that it will be helpful in understanding scala as well). 
I checked the source-code for reading data from "textFile" under : "core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala ". I saw there was a reference to "withScope"   i.e

def textFile(
      path: String,
      minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String] = **withScope** {
......}

I checked the **"withScope"** implementation under  "/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDDOperationScope.scala" but I am not able to understand clearly what the "withScope" does from the sourcecode .

Kindly help me understand what "withScope" does with an example or redirect to sources that will help me in understanding what it does?

Thanks

Comment: Not able to locate your mentioned line in [RDDOperationScope.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDDOperationScope.scala). Which branch you are using or can you point to the source-code ?

Comment: which line are you referring to ?this one "def textFile( path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String] = withScope { ......} " ?? This is from the "core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala"